# Conditional Binomial Variables with co-related 'p'

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution

$ X_1 \sim Bin(n , p1) , X_2 \sim Bin(n , p2)$ are dependent R.V. and,  p1 and p2 are such that:

$$
V \sim Uniform(a , b): 
$$
$$
p1 = P[V < r_1]
$$
$$
p2 = P[V < r_2]
$$

(1) Comment on the distribution of $X_2 | X_1$ , what simplifying assumptions would you make to make the calculations of the $E[X_2 | X_1]$ and  $E[X_2 | X_1<s]$ tractable.

I know that if $X_1 \sim Bin(n , p)$ and $X_2|X_1 \sim Bin(n , q)$ then $X_2\sim Bin(n , pq)$.

So I am thinking that if we assume that $X_2 | X_1$ is Binomial and p2 < p1 and does that necessarily imply that $X_2 | X_1 \sim Bin(n, p2 / p1)$ in this case?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: We would need the distribution of the vector $(X_1,X_2)$. What are $r_1$ and $r_2$ in this context? Parameters?